# F# piping a quadruple to a function

Tags: f#

A tuple is piped by:

```
let a = (1,2)
let f a b = ()
a ||> f
```

A triple is piped by:

```
let a = (1,2,3)
let f a b c = ()
a |||> f
```

But this doesn't work for a quadruple:

```
let a = (1,2,3,4)
let f a b c d= ()
a ||||> f
```

How do you pipe a quadruple to a function?

Comment: Any reason not to do `let f (a, b, c, d) = ()`?

Comment: @Daniel : At the least, you lose the capacity for partial application.

Comment: At the point where you're passing in a quadruple perhaps you want to consider using a Record.  4 anonymous pieces of data in a parameter list is starting to approach hard to understand.

Comment: Ya, maybe i should just use a record. but still, i was curious about this.

Comment: Note that 4-tuples are a code smell. You want to start naming fields before then, i.e. switch from tuples to records or classes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The others are defined by F#, for a 4-tuple you need to define it yourself:

```
let a = (1,2,3,4)
let f a b c d = printfn "got %A %A %A %A" a b c d

let inline (||||>) (a,b,c,d) f = f a b c d

a ||||> f
```

Comment: Best to make it `inline` as well, like the builtin piping operators.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it the boring way, or...

```
let a = (1,2,3,4)
let f a b c d = ()
let g = OptimizedClosures.FSharpFunc<_,_,_,_,_>.Adapt(f)
a |> g.Invoke
```